# How to display two tables separately in a single view with a join query in one table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am creating a dashboard in ASP.NET MVC using C# and Entity Framework.

I have two tables

1. `Tbl_Channel` (Id, Channel_Name)
2. `Tbl_News` (Id, Channel_Id, News_Title, News_Description)

When I tried this query:

```
 public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
       ShowData model = new ShowData();
       var rs1 = (from c in db.Tbl_Channel select c).ToList();

       var rs2 = (from c in db.Tbl_News
                  join d in db.Tbl_Channel on c.Channel_Id equals d.Id
                  select new
                         {
                              c.Id,
                              c.News_Title,
                              c.News_Description,
                              d.Channel_Name
                         })
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                 .ToList();

       model.tbl_ChannelData = rs1;
       model.tbl_NewsData = rs2;

       return View(model);
}
```

I get the following error in line model.tbl_NewsData = rs2:

Model class :

```
public class ShowData
{
    public List<Tbl_Channel> tbl_ChannelData { get; set; }
    public List<Tbl_News> tbl_NewsData { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

The output I want to display be like:

```
(Id, Channel_Name, News_Title, News_Description)
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context? Is this statement inside a method with a return value? If you really only have a `var query` variable, then this error shouldn't happen

Comment: @marc_s I updated the question. please review it

Comment: In model class i create a list of that table and in controller class im trying to bind the query in model, means the Channel name comes in query but the model class did not find that attribute in tbl_news.. so i just want to know whats the actual code to achieve the result i want. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Changing query to this one maybe it work:

```
  var query = (from c in db.tblnews 
                 join d in db.tblchannel on c.Channel_Id equals d.Id 
                 Select new Data()
                        {
                            Id = c.Id,
                            News_Title= c.News_Title,
                            News_Description= c.News_Description,
                            Channel_Name= d.Channel_Name
                         })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                .ToList();


return View(query)
```

create this class:

```
public class Data
{
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string News_Title{ get; set; }
        public string News_Description{ get; set; }
        public string Channel_Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this line model.tbl_NewsData have problem because you want to add anonymous type to model.tbl_NewsData, you should create a class with that property (Id, Channel_Name, News_Title, News_Description) and cast your select to that.

Comment: I already tried like this but i did not find a way to return the query. it will be very helpful for me if you write the code for the controller. Thank You

Comment: @inżynier umair  at first say to me with this way your error resolved?

Comment: @hassen.ef
No sir, getting the same error after creating model class or what ever im trying to achive the result. :(

Comment: @inżynier umair edit your question and put both of your model here

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is this: you have defined your properties in the model class like this:

```
public class ShowData
{
    public List<Tbl_Channel> tbl_ChannelData { get; set; }
    public List<Tbl_News> tbl_NewsData { get; set; }
}
```

Yet, your query selects an **anonymous** type:

```
  select new
         {
             c.Id,
             c.News_Title,
             c.News_Description,
             d.Channel_Name
         }
```

This causes the error. What you need to do is instantiate objects of the type defined on your model class, e.g.

```
  select new Tbl_News
         {
             c.Id,
             c.News_Title,
             c.News_Description,
             d.Channel_Name
         }
```

or if this anonymous type doesn't match any existing type yet, you need to define a suitable type

```
public class ChannelAndNews
{
     public int ChannelId { get; set; }
     public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
     public string NewsDescription { get; set; }
     public string ChannelName { get; set; }
}
```

and create instances of that type, which you can then assign to the model class properties:

```
select new ChannelAndNews
         {
             ChannelId = c.Id,
             NewsTitle = c.News_Title,
             NewsDescription = c.News_Description,
             ChannelName = d.Channel_Name
         }
```

Comment: @marc_c ok , i tried this now, what should i write in  the line where i got error :

ie. model.??? = rs2;

Comment: You need to have a property in your model class `public List<ChannelAndNews> channelAndNews`, and then you can use `model.channelAndNews = rs2;`

Comment: Thank You So Much. It works.. i was stuck there from 3 days.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your Expected Result:[Just Assumption]
[[image: Tables & Data]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLOfP.png)
The Classes Needed:[In Your Case]

```
public class Tbl_Channel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Channel_Name { get; set; }
}

public class Tbl_News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Channel_Id { get; set; }
    public string News_Title { get; set; }
    public string News_Description { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelsAndNews
{
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string Channel_Name { get; set; }
    public string News_Title { get; set; }
    public string News_Description { get; set; }
}

public class ShowData
{
    public List<Tbl_Channel> Channels { get; set; }
    public List<Tbl_News> News { get; set; }
    public List<ChannelsAndNews> ChannelsAndNews { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller Method: [Changes]

```
public ActionResult ShowData()
    {            
        // GetChannels() & GetNews()  -- Seeded Locally in your case from DB.
        var showDataModel = new ShowData();
        showDataModel.Channels = (from channel in GetChannels() select channel).ToList();
        showDataModel.News = (from news in GetNews() select news).ToList();
        showDataModel.ChannelsAndNews = (from channel in GetChannels()
                                         join news in GetNews() on channel.Id equals news.Channel_Id
                                         select new ChannelsAndNews
                                         {
                                             ChannelId = channel.Id,
                                             Channel_Name = channel.Channel_Name,
                                             News_Title = news.News_Title,
                                             News_Description = news.News_Description
                                         })
                                         .OrderByDescending(channelnews => channelnews.ChannelId)
                                         .ToList();
        return View(showDataModel);
    }
```

This just seems to be working fine.